# Translation of plugin in MU-PLUGINS directory not working

Tags: translation, mu-plugins

I have successfully translated a child theme, but not the same result in mu-plugins folder.

The name of the plugin is "mu-functions.php".
In this file I have added the "Text Domain: mu-functions" in the header and then I have loaded the textdomain:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_muload_textdomain' );
function myplugin_muload_textdomain() {
load_muplugin_textdomain( 'mu-functions', basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/inc/languages' );
}
```

The structure of the plugin that I have created in the mu-plugins directory is the following:

In the same directory I have a "inc"(include) folder where I put all the other files that are being called through the "include_once()" function in "mu-function.php" file. 
Along with this files, in the same "inc" folder directory, I have the "languages" folder where I have created the "mu-functions.pot" file that has been translated to Portuguese and then generated to both ".mo" and ".po" files.

In my child theme I had an issue with these ".mo" and ".po" files. I have found in another forum that I had to name them only by the locale (so in this case "pt_PT") and not "Text-Domain-pt_PT". This issue has been successfully solved.
Being so, for testing purposes I have generated 2 more other ".mo" and ".po" files.
These are the files that are in my languages folder:

- mu-functions-pt_PT.mo
- mu-functions-pt_PT.po
- mu-functions.pot
- pt_PT.mo
- pt_PT.po

Can anybody, please, help me? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another action when in a mu-plugins.

```
add_action('muplugins_loaded', 'myplugin_muload_textdomain');
```

`plugins_loaded` action work only after active plugins and pluggable functions are loaded.

mu-plugins are not regular plugins and will not be loaded like them.

As you can see in the following link, mu-plugins are loaded before anything else. [Actions Run During a Typical Request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer and link for the Plugin API.
It definitely helped, but it's still missing something else.

Comment: What's happen if you put you languages file in wp-content/languages/mu-plugins/ ?

Comment: I made sure to assign a new path that points into the "inc/" folder when placing in the catalog properties [witch gave me something like "../../mu-plugins/inc/"]. However nothing has changed.

Comment: Then I remembered to change the function
'function myplugin_muload_textdomain() {
 load_muplugin_textdomain( 'mu-functions', basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/languages/mu-plugins' );
}'
but not successful

Comment: No something like WP_CONTENT . '/languages/mu-plugins/your-slug/...

Comment: Now I was confused by noting that for example the contact form 7 plugin has .po and .mo files both in the plugin's own directory and in the "wp-content / languages / plugins" directory.
I've never questioned this directory because I've always thought this directory "wp-content / languages / plugins" was from files that are subject to general and automatic updates of both wordpress and every referrer theme or plugin.

Comment: Now my current code from my "mu-functions.php" file is:
Function myplugin_muload_textdomain () {
Load_muplugin_textdomain ('mu-functions', WP_CONTENT. '/ Languages / mu-plugins');
}

I do not know what you meant when you referred to "your-slug / ..." but I assume it's to make sure I have the file named "mu-functions-pt_PT.po" and "mu-functions-pt_PT.mo".

Unfortunately, it's not all yet set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line:

```
load_muplugin_textdomain( 'mu-functions', basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/inc/languages' );
```

and more specifically the function:

```
basename( dirname(__FILE__) )
```

Since my plugin and language folder is in the root of mu-plugins folder, the correct code is:

```
load_muplugin_textdomain( 'mu-functions', 'lang' );
```

I've found more info in that in the following links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url
http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/what-does-dirname__file__-and-basenamedirname__file__-do/

I guess I have to play more to understand it if I want to put my plugin as a subdirectory mu-plugin folder.

Sorry for the delay Benoti, and thank you for the support!